# Создание CSV файла с переменной в названии

Tags: python, csv

Переменная `Idd` должна взять атрибут `id` и создавать CSV файл с названием атрибута:

```
Idd = collapse.get_attribute('id')
with open(".csv", 'w') as f:
    f.write("blablabla")
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: with open(id + ".csv", 'w') as f:

Comment: Спасибо, работает